# Upload file using React frontend app and Spring (Java) backend app

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have a project uses Java's Spring as backend and React as frontend and I want to upload a file to the server.
In the backend, I have a Spring controller with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping("/upload-file")
public void uploadFile (MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest) {
    //save on server logic comes here
}
```

On frontend, I want to use some npm library to upload the file. 
The problem is that non of the libraries I found sends the file in a way Spring controller can handle. 
Maybe I'm missing something: What is the best way to upload a file from react frontend to Spring backend?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) to upload files, not sure will it be compatible with Spring. You can give a try.

An example how to use it

```
<div className='dropzone'>
      <Dropzone
        name={name}
        multiple={false}
        onDrop={(filesToUpload, e) => {
          return input.onChange(filesToUpload)
        }}>

      </Dropzone>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Frontend: if you are using [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) as offered earlier, you could use the following code to send request with files:

```
    onDrop(accepted, rejected) {
        if (rejected.length) {
            //do something with rejected files
        } else {
            let data = new FormData();
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.files.length; i++) {
                let file = accepted[i];
                data.append("file" + i, file, file.name);
            }
            const config = {
                headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p' }
            };
            axios.post("upload-files", data, config);
        }
    };
```

Backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-files", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(@RequestParam(value = "file0", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile, Integer adminOid) throws IOException {
    //do something with the multipartFile
}
```